# onActivityResult calling before the started activity finish

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity

I have App1 (cordova app) and calling activity of App2. here is a App1 code

```
 mContext.startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE_COMMUNICATION_APP);
```

have implemented following onActivityResult in App1

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == this.REQUEST_CODE_COMMUNICATION_APP) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { ....
```

Now here is a finish() method of a actvity of App2

```
public void finishWithResult() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent());
    finish();
}
```

Now problem is that when activity started by startActivityForResult from App1, immediately onActivityResult method is triggering in App1. However it should be called when i activity of App2 call finishWithResult(). Can someone tell me where i am making mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent in = caller.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.your.package.here");
```

Which would create an `intent` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` added by default, so call:
`in.setFlags(0);`
Which will clear that flag, and then you can proceed to:

```
startActivityForResult(in, action);
```